# Source for the story about the Satmar Rebbe

Tags: sources-mekorot, pronunciation, satmar, story-identification

I remember a story about a *maskil* who approached the Satmar Rebbe, and who lamented the fact that Hungarian Jews don't differentiate between the *samekh* (ס), the *sin* (שׂ) and the *sav* (ת). The Satmar Rebbe's response was, "וכסילים מתי תשכילו" - a quote from Tehillim 94:8, meaning "O fools, when will you gain wisdom?" Brilliantly, of course, this passuk features all three of the consonants to which the *maskil* was referring.

I don't remember where I first heard this, but I very recently heard it again in [this lecture](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/733495/Rabbi_Aharon_Kahn/Customs:_Prayer_-_Pronunciation) by R' Aharon Kahn (at the 6:50 mark).

Does anybody have a printed source for this story?

Comment: I saw somewhere R' Ben Zion Mutzafi quoted R' Ya'akov Emden as applying that verse to people who do not differentiate (which would of course predate the Satmar Rebbe).

Comment: Regarding your original question, see [נהג כצאן יוסף](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8905&st=&pgnum=64) (see #9 on the linked page, though it doesn't identify the Satmar Rebbe's as such).

Comment: @Fred - that would be very interesting, given what the Yaavetz says in his siddur! (I asked another question about that [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53498/may-one-mix-and-match-to-create-their-own-hebrew-pronunciation), in which I quoted the relevant passage.)

Comment: @Fred - also, the passage you bring is interesting in that it applies this story with the opposite intention (ie: to show the foolhardiness of those who confuse these consonants, rather than of those who are displeased with their confusion).

Comment: More generally: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66135

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8905&st=&pgnum=64&hilite= I think this is older I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the [Hakdomoh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20289&st=&pgnum=28) to  דברי יואל - שו"ת - חלק א

> שאל אותו אחד מן המתחדשים שרצה להתעולל עמו, כיון שהאותיות ״ ס ׳ ש׳ ת׳״
>   שוין הם במבטא מה צורך יש בשלשת! והי׳ די באחד מהם, ורבינו מבלי לחשוב
>   אפילו רגע השיב לו מיד, א״כ איך הי׳ נכתב הפסוק ״וכסילים מתי תשכילו״

Comment: Fantastic - thank you! Does "מתחדשים" refer to the "neologs"? I don't think I've seen that term before.

Comment: The second definition of NEOLOGY in [Merriam-Webster](www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neology) is "a new doctrine; especially :  a new method of theological interpretation". 
So I think that the neologs can be rightly described as מתחדשים.