# Bons-mots of R' Yoel Teitelbaum

Tags: product-recommendation, books-generally, quotations, chassidic-rebbe, satmar

I've heard many Judaism-related witticisms attributed to the Satmar Rebbe over the years, often without sources. This has led me to wonder whether a compendium, preferably sourced, of R' Yoel Teitelbaum's *bons-mots* exists.

Does it and if so, where could it be found?